# Saving Files with SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to save Files with SaveFileDialog but they are not appearing on the Directory i have given.
This is what i have tried:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath + "\\Scripts\\";      
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save text Files";
    saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
    saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = textBox1.Text;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    Executor executor = new Executor();
    this.Hide();
}
```

What could be the Problem?

Comment: Where is the saving part? Use File.WriteAllText() or StreamWriter to write text to file.

Comment: Using File.WriteAllText i am getting System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException tho the Directory exists @Abhay

Comment: make sure you are passing saveFileDialog1.FileName or FileNames based on your file selection(s).

Comment: The purpose of the SaveFileDialog is to retrieve a path from the user.  This is accomplished via the `ShowDialog()` call.  After getting an "OK" response back, you use the `FileName` property to retrieve the filename (including the path).

Comment: @Abhay i have only one file to save

Comment: @Idle_Mind ok gotta try that. update its opening the window but the file name section is empty. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()
{
    InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath + "\\Scripts\\",
    Title = "Save Text Files",
    CheckPathExists = true,
    DefaultExt = "txt",
    Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
    FilterIndex = 1,
    RestoreDirectory = true
};

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, "your data here...");
}
```

- You don't need to assign filename, if you know filename then no use of savefiledialog just directly use File.WriteAllText method with filename.
- No need to check if file exists cause user might have to create new one
- If you want to append text then use AppendAllText Method of File class.